# Media creation tool for Windows 10 gets stuck on 50% progress when writing to pen drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, media-creation-tool

I've used the tool many times in the past without any problems but since September I can't get it to work. I've tried media creation tool versions 1903 and 1909. I'm even holding on to old Windows 10 v. 1809 USB sticks because of this.

It all goes smoothly until the last progress meter hits 50%. I've read that this could be due to a faulty USB drive but I've tested more than a dozen that appear to function with other uses.

Saving the image to ISO also works without any problems.

EDIT: Apparently the problem is with my computer. The same version of the media creation tool and the same usb drive worked fine in another computer. Does anyone know where the log files for the creation tool are stored?

Comment: Could it be a bad ISO?

Comment: @harrymc the tool downloads an up to date image from Microsoft on the fly and creates a bootable USB drive or ISO image. This is the official tool from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-en/software-download/windows10).

Comment: Try eliminating all the various possibilities, one at a time: try with two different ISOs, then two different USB drives, then try the option which doesn't save an ISO and creates the bootable media directly. Then try downloading the media creation tool again in case the first executable was corrupted. Then try the same flash drive with another PC. What size is this flash drive? It needs to be 8 GB minimum. My guess would be a problem with the flash drive itself. I've read about other people who had the same issue and the problem followed their flash drives around between different PCs.

Comment: Try to burn the ISO using another software. There are lots of them around, see [random article](https://www.passmoz.com/make-bootable-dvd-from-iso-file.html).

Comment: You should try Rufus.

Comment: @iceburn_pt The logs should be written to one of the subdirectories in the hidden folder (there may be two) the Media Creation Tool uses at the root of the `C:` partition.  There's likely documentation on [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/), but it would likely be quicker to just do a terminal search for `*.log` and `*.txt` files.

Answer (score 0):

I also just recently had this issue the progress bar would stop at 50% and not progress any further.

I solved my issue with a bit of troubleshooting, I'll list what I did in hopes is helps anyone with this issue in the future.

I enabled several services listed on another troubleshooting forum:

1. Press Windows key + R, type services.msc, and hit Enter.
   On the list of services, find the services listed below and check their status. The Startup Type of them all should be set to Automatic.

- Windows Update
- Background Intelligent Transfer Service
- Server
- Workstation
- TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
- IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules

2. I turned off MalwareBytes (Anti-Virus)
3. I turned off WebRoot secure Anywhere (Anti-Virus)
4. I turned off Adguard (Ad-Blocker Application)
5. I ran the creation tool as an administrator by right clicking on the tool icon.
6. I used a band new 32 GB USB 3.0 Flash drive, In-case my old 16 GB one was faulty or the size of the files somehow exceeded 16 GB, the tool states it only needs 8 GB

Between all of these steps listed above one or more of them allowed the media creation tool to progress past 50%, only took about an hour to finish the install give or take.

Comment: For me it was the Anti-Virus.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, simply running as administrator fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. For me it was because the USB was formatted as FAT32, then i formatted it to NTFS and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, first try it got stuck on 1%, second try got stuck on 13%. Third try I turned off AVG antivirus and it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).